# Installed script with tkinter module returns error

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tcl, filenotfounderror

I tried to convert my tkinter.py script to the tkinter.exe file. I used PyInstaller and I am sure the command was right, so no questions about PyInstaller. When conversion had completed I tried to execute but get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth__tkinter.py", line 25, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: Tcl data directory "C:\Users\sashk\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI42002\tcl" not found.
```

This error is related to tkinter module exactly and I can't find any solutions on the Web, please help.

[image: Screen with Error]

Comment: Don't name your script `tkinter.py`.

Comment: it doesn't affect anything

Comment: It works for me if the script is renamed to, for example, `tkdemo.py` as long as it is not `tkinter.py`.

Comment: It seems you were right, after rename and new convertation I can execute it

Comment: Please add an answer so people in the future with this problem can find the solution more easily.

Comment: As I said - just renamed my file. I don't know how to add a solution on this site sorry

Answer (score 0):

I've renamed to Demo.py and it's started to work.